# how to plot different datafiles, saved in certain format, into a single plot using gnuplot script

Tags: gnuplot

I have file named 1000_0.dat, 2000_0.dat,... and similarly 1000_1.dat, 2000_1.dat,... how to plot all the files into a single plot using gnuplot script? 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is

```
plot 'data1.dat', 'data2.dat' ...
```

Just separate the data files with commas.  You can also put each file name on a different line if you want it to be easier to read,

```
plot 'data1.dat', \
     'data2.dat'
```

If you want to totally automate it, you can use the `for` syntax in the newer (4.6+) versions of gnuplot:

```
plot for [i=0:1] for [j=1e3:2e3:1e3] ''.j.'_'.i.'.dat' title ''.j.'_'.i.'.dat'
```

This is a doubly nested loop which will plot all the files and label them appropriately.  `.` is the string concatenation operator in gnuplot.  I set the title manually because otherwise it displays `''.j.'_'.i.'.dat'` for all the plots.  The leading `''` before the file name and title is because gnuplot won't recognize that it should print the index `i` or `j` as a string unless it comes after another string, in this case an empty one.